# Missing name after . operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problem figuring out, what exactly is going wrong here,
The thing that I understand is `this` keyword is causing the problem but I can't figure out how and why.

I have tried `$(this)` and `(this)`

```
function makeChoice(){
    $(".choices").click(".js-choice", function(){
        var choice = this.(".js-choice").val();
    });
    console.log(choice);
}
```

I'm creating a quiz app that has 4 options for each question, and for each answer there is a class `js-choice` and I want the answer from only the button that is clicked currently.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".js-start-quiz").click(".start-button",function(){
  $(".js-start-quiz").hide();
  $(".question-container").show();
  makeChoice();
 })
});
`

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid use of the `click` method.  What are you attempting to do with the `.js-choice` selector as the first argument?  It looks like you have half a direct binding and half a delegate binding

Comment: The error is because `this.("js-choice")` is not valid way of accessing object property ... in this case it's `this["js-choice"]` - however that will just fail too, since `this` is unlikely to have a property called `js-choice` with a `val` method - however, this explains the error you are getting

Comment: there are 4 choices to a question, each of them has a `class` in common `js-choice` and each of them have a separate value for answer, and I want to pick the value from one that is currently clicked by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've potentially made a syntatical error with trying to create a delegate event handler.  If so this can be solved by fixing the binding.  And moving the log into the event handler.

```
function makeChoice(){
  $(".choices").on("click", ".js-choice", function(){
    var choice = $(this).val();
    console.log(choice);
  });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, well explained